# How I can view memory leaks in NetBeans for C++ application?

Tags: c++, netbeans, memory-leaks

How I can view memory leaks in NetBeans for C++ application? 
I see on Run Monitor, but I don't know how i can use this

[image]

Where I can see some manuals about this theme?

I find article [Uncovering Memory Leaks Using NetBeans Profiler](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html), but it's for java :(